# How do I store versions of consistently changing text with low cost?

Tags: text, storage, google-cloud-storage, versioning

I have been creating a text editor online, just for learning experience. I was curious what the best way to store multiple versions of a text file that is consistently changing is.

I've looked at a variety of options and I am yet to see a cheap, and scale-able option.

I've looked into Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3. The only issue is that too many requests to save the file start to add up a lot in cost. I'd like files to be saved practically instantly, and also versioned every so often. I've also looked into data deduplication which looks like a great option, but I have not yet found a way to do it without writing my own software.

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well I understand many of the different methods and I realize that in order to find the best method you have to try them. I was hoping someone else in the community may have tried the different methods and has found the best solution for what I was looking for. I have explained what I want to do. I want to store multiple versions of a text file that is consistently changing.

Comment: I understand what you mean when you say there is no best answer. I should not have stated it in this way. I mean't what is the most efficient way you are aware of to do this. As Brandon stated below, operational transformations seem like a good route of doing so. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but the basic answer is usually some flavor of Operational Transform. Basically you don't want to be constantly sending the entire document back and forth between the user(s) and the server, nor do you want to overwrite the whole of the document repeatedly. Instead you want to store diffs. Then you need to deal with the idea that multiple users might be changing the file simultaneously, but possibly in different areas, and dealing with that effectively.

Wikipedia has some good, formal discussion of the idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation

You wouldn't need all of that for a document that will only be edited by one person at a time, but even then, the answer is to think in terms of diffs from previous versions and only occasionally persist whole snapshots.